# How to track users using flurry for number of buying ticket events

Tags: android, flurry

In my app i want to track users for buying tickets.Means The total number of tickets bought from my app daily in a chart.Currently I am using `FlurryAgent.onEvent(String eventId, Map<String, String> parameters)`.but the map parameters takes String.I want to pass number of tickets through that.So that flurry will count all daily tickets bought from my app.
can anybody plz help me how i ll achive this.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one counter variable, 
int counter=0;
and each time user buys ticket increment it by one or number of tickets buyed.(depends on you). 
       After this use the below flurry code:

```
   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("NumTicketsBought", "" + counter);
   FlurryAgent.logEvent("NumberOfTicketsBought", params);
```

In your flurry analytics check for event NumberOfTicketsBought, it will show you the count of tickets bought, hope this helps.