# Android Flurry events are not reported on the dashboard

Tags: android, events, analytics, flurry

I have integrated Flurry in a test project. I am trying to send events to Flurry but they are not reported at all on the Flurry dashboard. I have followed carefully how to integrate it in my app:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();     
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}

public void sendEvent(View view){
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Page_Viewed");
}
```

The log of the device is:

```
12-06 10:46:53.692: W/FlurryAgent(2058): Start session
12-06 10:46:54.232: W/FlurryAgent(2058): FlurryDataSender: report eb66f44c-1a59-4b5d-82df-04a9bf5a086a sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK
12-06 10:47:00.972: W/FlurryAgent(2058): Event count started: Article_Read
```

I stop the app and I restart it:

```
12-06 10:47:18.302: W/FlurryAgent(2058): Trying to end session
12-06 10:47:28.313: W/FlurryAgent(2058): Ending session
12-06 10:47:33.193: W/FlurryAgent(2058): Start session
12-06 10:47:33.522: W/FlurryAgent(2058): FlurryDataSender: report 017075e6-91a6-44b6-a4a7-70cffec21f00 sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK
```

I have waited more than 48 hours and I still do not see anything on the dashboard. I am using the Flurry SDK version 3.3.1.

Comment: Please post the code that you used.

Comment: @TharakaNirmana I have just posted the code.

Comment: @poiuytrez Did you get this issue fixed?

Comment: see this how to use logEvent() http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136813/1765530

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it looks like you are doing everything correctly. The only problem might be that you are not calling the sendEvent() method which calls logEvent()... Or there might be something on the network that is blocking the communication with Flurry servers.